# How to say phpstan that class is replaced by child

Tags: phpstan

I have a laravel package for logging. It's used like this.

```php
activity()
   ->performedOn($model)
   ->causedBy($user)
   ->log('Look, I logged something');
```

The `activity()` helper returns the vendor class `ActivityLogger` which is take from the container by class name.

I have to add additional method to vendor logger, so code will look like:

```php
activity()
   ->performedOn($model)
   ->causedBy($user)
   ->relates('#123') // new decorator
   ->log('Look, I logged something');
```

I've created a child class and replaced in container the vendor class by new one. Everything works ok, except phpstan complaints about `relates` method not found in `ActivityLogger`.

Can I say phpstan that for my application, `ActivityLogger` is replaced by `MyActivityLogger` ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [stub files](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/stub-files) to overwrite the return type of `activity` function.

`stubs/activity.stub`:

```php
/**
 * @phpstan-param string $logName
 * @phpstan-return YOUR_CUSTOM_OBJECT_TYPE_HERE
 */
function activity(string $logName = null) {}
```

then in your `phpstan.neon` config file:

```
parameters:
    stubFiles:
        - stubs/activity.stub
```